# Raise event when movement occurs

Tags: video-processing, kinect, motion-detection

I'm using the Kinect SDK to read data in from a Kinect. At the minute I have an application which simply saves an image from the stream every few seconds and starts recording audio, however I only want this to execute code when movement is sensed (think security camera that starts recording when when movement is detected). I can't see any event which is raised in the code samples if movement is detected, the only thing even close being **nui_SkeletonFrameReady** which I could use (if I am correct) if a persons body is detected. Is there a simple way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no event raised in this scenario. What I did was subscribed to the image ready event which comes with the API and compared the previous image to the current image using the libraries at [AForge.net](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/).

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the Kinect runtime with the RuntimeOptions.UseSkeletalTracking flag to receive skeletal tracking data from the device:

```
var runtime = new Runtime();
runtime.Initialize(RuntimeOptions.UseSkeletalTracking| RuntimeOptions.UseDepthAndPlayerIndex | RuntimeOptions.UseColor);
```

Then subscribe to the SkeletonFrameReady event:

```
runtime.SkeletonFrameReady += nui_SkeletonFrameReady;
```

This event will fire continuously and you will need to iterate through the collection of six possible skeletons in the SkeletonFrame collection to determine if any are being tracked.

```
void nui_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
     SkeletonFrame allSkeletons = e.SkeletonFrame;

     //get the first tracked skeleton
     SkeletonData skeleton = (from s in allSkeletons.Skeletons
                         where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
                         select s).FirstOrDefault();

     if skeleton != null
     {
         // Start recording audio, etc
     }
}
```

More details and examples are found in this Channel 9 video:

[Skeletal Tracking Fundamentals](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectSDKQuickstarts/Skeletal-Tracking-Fundamentals)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't as clear as I could've been... I'm literally wanting to sense when movement occurs between frames, nothing to do with tracking/detecting skeletons. I mentioned that I am aware of the event which is raised when a skeleton is detected, but I was looking for a simple way to detect when any motion occurs. The best solution I have came across so far is a project from http://www.aforgenet.com where I can use it's detection to tell the difference between the latest image and the last image. I was hoping the API might contain something similar...